# Mouse click and hold event?

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone have an idea how to handle a mouse click and hold event  in VB.NET?

Suppose I want to click and hold in a button and do some stuff behind the code like change the button BackColor or close a window faster( just like when you click in the ms office 2013 file menu then use a left-arrow to close that menu).

Hope you know what I mean

Thank you

Comment: You need to think this through a bit.  Detecting a "hold" requires a timer.  When it ticks and the button is still down then you can fire a "Hold" event.  The word *faster* cannot possibly apply to this kind of gesture.  And there's a severe risk of accidents, the user just not being agile enough to click fast enough to avoid the event.  Your grandma isn't going to like it much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a timer that is defined globally that begins when MouseDown is called, then ends on Mouse Up. You can then set a condition on how many milliseconds need to pass before you deem it a 'long click'. See example code below:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim WithEvents timer As New Timer
Dim milliseconds As Integer


Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    timer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    timer.Stop()
    Label1.Text = "Button held down for: " & milliseconds & " milliseconds"
    If milliseconds >= 10 then 'Mouse has been down for one second
      DoSomething()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub EggTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
    milliseconds += 1
End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

MouseDown is what you are looking for